# Aligning items in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I am having trouble aligning my items in my `Gridview`. I have a `DataTemplate` that has a `Stackpanel` within it. Inside of that `Stackpanel` I have 3 `TextBlocks`. I am unable to move those textblock where I want to in the `Gridview`. I will post my XAML below..

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TileTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleView}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BodyView}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,50" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthorView}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,10" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

 <Grid x:Name="tileGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <GridView x:Name="tileGridView" Margin="12,60" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileTemplate}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="#2A2A2A"
                                  Margin="5"
                                  Height="200"
                                  Width="300">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
      </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

As you can see it is completely cutting out the Author and is not aligning my body correctly (via my inline styling of the textblock).

Does anyone know of a way I can manipulate the position of the textblocks in my GridView?

Comment: Is the horizontal orientation of your StackPanel intentional? I would think you would want a vertical orientation with Left Horizontal Alignment.

Comment: This question is unclear. We see the image showing what is happening. But how _specifically_ is that different from what you want? Please provide a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @Danielle if you would like to post that as a proposed solution I will mark it as correct

Comment: @PeterDuniho How do you see this as unclear? I clearly stated I am having problems manipulating the position of of textblocks in a gridview. I do not know where I want it positioned so it would be pointless to state that in the question

Comment: _"How do you see this as unclear"_ -- please read my comment, as it explains already how I see the question as unclear.  _"I do not know where I want it positioned"_ -- then how do you know the current behavior is wrong? It seems absurd to me that you would not know what the _expected output_ of your own program would be, but if you truly don't know what the expected output is, you have no business saying the current output isn't correct.

Comment: The question is "Does anyone know of a way I can manipulate the position of the textblocks in my GridView?" Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Code I must say I agree with Peter. I saw this question when you had just posted it and my first thought was "does he just want a vertical stack panel?", but I didn't post an answer because I wasn't sure of your intentions.  You merely mentioned that the text is cut off, and you wanted a way to manipulate it. Well, there are multiple ways to manipulate, and multiple ways to make it not cut off :) If you described the final positioning of the text blocks that you wanted, it would've been 100% clear. Anyway, glad you got your question answered :). Oh btw, you can also use a WrapPanel instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Orientation of the StackPanel to be Vertical with a Left Horizontal Alignment and see if that gives you the desired look.